# Is the entropy model fundamentally wrong?

Tags: entropy

By a popular definition, *"entropy quantifies the number Ω of microscopic configurations (known as microstates) that are consistent with the macroscopic quantities that characterize the system (such as its volume, pressure and temperature). **Under the assumption that each microstate is equally probable**, the entropy S is the natural logarithm of the number of microstates, multiplied by the Boltzmann constant kB"*.

The isolated system is thus represented as pebbles on a Go board or grains of sand in a sand pile or something similar. But this is obviously **WRONG** as Go pebbles are **not subject to Brownian motion** and therefore they stay put indefinitely as opposed to actual [gas] molecules that move all the time and at different speeds depending on temperature and pressure.

At the system level,  a compressed gas, once released will **NEVER** return spontaneously to its compressed state as proven by the ever increasing energy required to create both higher and lower pressure. This is the mark of a system that behaves nothing like the naïve entropy model predicts.

And if the current entropy model is fundamentally wrong, what would be the correct micro model?

Comment: Personal theories are off-topic here. We deal only with mainstream physics.

Comment: You are correct in observing that the standard introductory-level justification for statistical mechanics is incomplete. I suggest you ask a more specific question focused on that. The bits of your question about Brownian motion and compressed gasses don't quite make sense to me. You might be confused in more ways than you realize.

Comment: Also, some more general advice: Physicists have a well-known allergy to unusual typefaces.

Comment: I don't find that an isolated system is compared to stones on a Go board or grains of sand in the textbooks I have used.

Comment: What "personal theory"? Is the entropy model not mainstream physics? Isn't the mainstream physics assumption that each microstate is equally probable? Doesn't that include the microstates where all the gas is concentrated in a corner of the chamber?

Answer (score 2):

> ...actual [gas] molecules that move all the time and at different
> speeds depending on temperature and pressure.

When that model is applied to ideal gases, following Boltzmann distribution, the energy states are exactly related to their movements. $E_k = \frac{p_k^2}{2m}$. It is not required that the molecules are frozen at fixed locations.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. How does your comment answer my question?